# Showing if a vector in a span is a linear combination of the other vectors, the other vectors still span the subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

lets say we have a subspace $W$ and that three vectors, $w1, w2$ and $w3$ span $W$. 
I want to show that if $w3$ is a linear combination of $w1$ and $w2$, that $w1$ and $w2$ still span $W$

My attempt so far:
so we can write $w3$ = $(c1*w1)$ + $(c2*w2)$ for $c1,c2$ not all $0$

I'm stuck at this point and can't think of how to prove the first statement, any suggestions?

edit:
[image: question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x\in W$.

Then $x=sw_1+tw_2+uw_3$ for some $s,t,u$, by assumption.   So $x=sw_1+tw_2+u(c_1w_1+c_2w_2)=(s+uc_1)w_1+(t+uc_2)w_2$. Thus $\operatorname{span}\{w_1,w_2\}=W$.

Comment: thanks for the reply! , now that you've shown $w1,w2$ still span $W$ how should i go about proving $w1,w2$ are linearly independent

Comment: im thinking i have to show $(s+uc1)w1+(t+uc2)w2 = 0$ only when the coefficients are $0$?

Comment: They may not be linearly independent.

Comment: true, i'm trying to show that the dimension of $W$ is $>=2$ and $<=2$ to show that $dimW=2$    
so showing the $span{w1,w2}=W$ shows that $dimW >=2$, now im trying to show that $dimW <= 2$

Comment: If two vectors span $W$ then $\operatorname{dim}W\le2$, actually.

Comment: so how do i show $\operatorname{dim}W\ge2$ ? so that together i can show $\operatorname{dim}W\ = 2$

Comment: We would need some more information to do that.

Comment: I'll add the question into the edit of the original question, its part (c) im referring too

Comment: The dimension of $W$ is at least two because $v_1,v_2\in W$ are linearly independent.